# How to create a DAE file to use in SceneKit?

Tags: swift, xcode, scenekit, arkit, maya

How do you create a `.dae` file from a 3D model? I've created a 3D model from a drone areal mapping and now have a very large file I can import in to Photoshop, but I can't figure out how to create a `.dae` file I can use in SceneKit.

The default game example for Xcode has a SceneKit that shows a rotating aircraft, and the asset is a `.dae` file, but I don't see any documentation on how to create one of those from a 3D model, and how to correctly apply a texture to it.

Comment: Seems like there should be a tutorial out there somewhere that explains how to start with a 3d model .OBJ file, and using Photoshop or some other similar tool and Xcode, explain how to create the sample SceneKit starter project you see in Xcode 6.1 currently.  Let me know if anyone has found something like that.

Comment: Most 3D modeling software can export to COLLADA files (.dae). Try one of those. As this question is currently phrased, it is not about ptogramming.

Comment: similar question: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/14584/properly-export-collada-for-use-in-scenekit

Comment: This [article](http://blog.manbolo.com/2014/08/10/import-cheetah3d-model-in-scenekit) might help you

Answer (score 3):

To create a 3D model and export it as a Collada `.dae` file you can use any of the following 3D authoring tools: Autodesk Maya, Blender, Autodesk 3dsMax, The Foundry Modo, Maxon Cinema 4D, SideFX Houdini, etc. The simplest way is to use a non-commercial student version of Autodesk Maya 2024. It's free. You can download it from [HERE](https://www.autodesk.com/education/free-software/maya).

There are countless examples in `YouTube` how to model and uv-map in Maya software. [Look at this example of UV-mapping in Maya](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HLhazEa8wmw). So, when your 3D model (and its UV-texture) is ready for use, you can export it as one of the five formats supported by SceneKit:

- animated Collada `DAE`
- animated Pixar `USDZ`
- animated Autodesk `FBX`
- single-frame Sony `Alembic`
- single-frame Wavefront `OBJ` with `MTL`

[image]

For exporting `DAE` models, in Maya `Export Type` choose `DAE_FBX export`:

[image]

You can export a 2K UV-mapped texture as `JPEG` or `PNG` file.

[image]

You must assign this UV-mapped square texture to a **`Diffuse`** slot of properties in `Lighting Model` (shader) in `Show the Material` Inspector.

[image]

And here's how you can do it programmatically:

```
import SceneKit

let scene = SCNScene(named: "art.scnassets/mushroom.scn")!

let mushroom = scene.rootNode.childNode(withName: "mushroom", 
                                     recursively: true)!

let mushroomMaterial = SCNMaterial()
mushroomMaterial.diffuse.contents = UIImage(named: "mushroom.png")
mushroom.geometry.materials = [mushroomMaterial]
```

#### P. S.

Working with Pixar's USDZ file format:

If you need to generate `.usdz` file, use the following command in Terminal:

```
usdzconvert file.fbx
```

Here you can read about [usdzconvert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50846627/how-to-create-usdz-file-using-xcode-converter/50867018#50867018) command.