# How to create USDZ file using Xcode converter?

Tags: swift, bash, scenekit, arkit, realitykit

At the 2018 WWDC Apple [announced](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2018/603/) the introduction of new USDZ file format.

In relation to creating USDZ file the following was said:

To create your own usdz files, a usdz_converter has been bundled as part of Xcode 10 beta. Its a command line tool for creating the usdz file from OBJ files, Single-frame Alembic (ABC) files, USD file (either .usda or usd.c)

the basic command line is

```
xcrun usdz_converter myFile.obj myFile.usdz
```

I have installed Xcode 10 beta, but have been unable to run or even find usdz_converter in the Xcode 10 beta bundle made available on the 4th June 2018 (build 10L176w).

note: I’m still running on macOS highSierra, I have not installed macOS Mojave 10.14 beta yet... but didn’t think that should be the reason why.

Has anyone else been able to get this xcrun usdz_converter to work?

If so please share the steps.

Comment: What do you get when you run the command?  I don't have a file to try to convert but when I run the command it prints out the usage description so it is at least there.

Comment: xcrun: error: unable to find utility "usdz_converter", not a developer tool or in PATH

Comment: Make sure xcrun is looking in the right place, either by using `xcode-select` to set the active developer directory to the one in the Xcode-beta.app or giving it the full path to `usdz_converter`

Comment: Ok, I have a couple of version of Xcode... so will look into that now. thanks

Comment: xcode-select -p
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer    should be /Applications/Xcode-beta 10.app/Contents/Developer - thanks

Comment: ok this fixed the problem .   sudo xcode-select --switch "/Applications/Xcode-beta 10.app/Contents/Developer"

Answer (score 37):

**Updated: July 03, 2023**.

### `usdzconvert` command in Xcode 15, 14, 13, 12, 11

> In *macOS Sonoma*, *Ventura*, *Monterey*, *Big Sur* and *Catalina* `USDZ converter` has a rich set of commands, and supports more input formats for conversion. But before using it you need to download and install [USDZ Tools](https://developer.apple.com/augmented-reality/tools/). And don't forget to setup **global variables** for Python usdz tools. Here's how a new command looks in **Terminal**:

```
usdzconvert ~/Desktop/file.gltf -diffuseColor albedo.png -metallic brass.jpg
```

- *In macOS Sonoma, Ventura, Monterey, Big Sur, Catalina, the default command shell is* ***ZSH***.

### Create Shell Resource file

If you want to use **`USDPython` tools** you need to create a Shell Resource file `.zshrc`.

For that go to Home area using `change directory` command in Terminal:

```zsh
cd /Users/<UserName>
```

Check whether you are there or not with `parent working directory` command:

```zsh
pwd
```

Then type `ls` command for `listing` of directory's content including hidden files:

```zsh
ls -a
```

Now you are ready to create a hidden `.zshrc` file:

```zsh
touch ~/.zshrc
```

Open this file using the following command:

```zsh
open ~/.zshrc
```

Now you can add these lines into zsh resource file:

```
export PATH="/Users/yourUserName/usdpython/USD:$PATH"
export PATH="/Users/yourUserName/usdpython/usdzconvert:$PATH"
export PYTHONPATH="/Users/yourUserName/usdpython/USD/lib/python:$PYTHONPATH"

echo "Now I can use USDPython commands here."
```

Save it and restart Terminal.

`usdzconvert` is a Python script that converts the following assets into `usdz`:

- obj
- gltf
- fbx
- abc
- usd – you can export it from Maya 2024
- usda
- usdc

If you need to use `FBX` format conversion you have to download and install FBX Python SDK.

Then add to `.zshrc` file one more line:

```
export PYTHONPATH="/Applications/Autodesk/FBXPythonSDK/2020.0.1/lib/Python27_ub:$PYTHONPATH"
```

Save `.zshrc` file and restart Terminal.

Here's a full list of options you can see in Terminal, typing **`usdzconvert -h`** :

```shell
# DO NOT USE usdzconvert 0.63 BECAUSE IT CAUSES ERRORS.

# USE usdzconvert 0.66, or usdzconvert 0.65, or usdzconvert 0.64

outputFile                           Output .usd/usda/usdc/usdz files.
-h, --help                           Show this help message and exit.
-f <file>                            Read arguments from <file>
-v                                   Verbose output.
-url <url>                           Add URL metadata
-copyright "copyright message"       Add copyright metadata
-copytextures                        Copy texture files (for .usd/usda/usdc) workflows
-metersPerUnit value                 Set metersPerUnit attribute with float value
-loop                                Set animation loop flag to 1
-no-loop                             Set animation loop flag to 0
-m materialName                      Subsequent material arguments apply to this material.
-iOS12                               Make output file compatible with iOS 12 frameworks
-texCoordSet name                    The name of the texture coordinates to use for current material.
                        
-diffuseColor r,g,b                  Set diffuseColor to constant color r,g,b with values in the range [0 .. 1]
-diffuseColor <file> fr,fg,fb        Use <file> as texture for diffuseColor.
                                     fr,fg,fb: (optional) constant fallback color, with values in the range [0..1].
                        
-normal x,y,z                        Set normal to constant value x,y,z in tangent space [(-1, -1, -1), (1, 1, 1)].
-normal <file> fx,fy,fz              Use <file> as texture for normal.
                                     fx,fy,fz: (optional) constant fallback value, with values in the range [-1..1].
                        
-emissiveColor r,g,b                 Set emissiveColor to constant color r,g,b with values in the range [0..1]
-emissiveColor <file> fr,fg,fb       Use <file> as texture for emissiveColor.
                                     fr,fg,fb: (optional) constant fallback color, with values in the range [0..1].
                        
-metallic c                          Set metallic to constant c, in the range [0..1]
-metallic ch <file> fc               Use <file> as texture for metallic.
                                     ch: (optional) texture color channel (r, g, b or a).
                                     fc: (optional) fallback constant in the range [0..1]
                        
-roughness c                         Set roughness to constant c, in the range [0..1]
-roughness ch <file> fc              Use <file> as texture for roughness.
                                     ch: (optional) texture color channel (r, g, b or a).
                                     fc: (optional) fallback constant in the range [0..1]
                        
-occlusion c                         Set occlusion to constant c, in the range [0..1]
-occlusion ch <file> fc              Use <file> as texture for occlusion.
                                     ch: (optional) texture color channel (r, g, b or a).
                                     fc: (optional) fallback constant in the range [0..1]
                        
-opacity c                           Set opacity to constant c, in the range [0..1]
-opacity ch <file> fc                Use <file> as texture for opacity.
                                     ch: (optional) texture color channel (r, g, b or a).
                                     fc: (optional) fallback constant in the range [0..1]

-clearcoat c                         Set clearcoat to constant c, in the range [0..1]
-clearcoat ch <file> fc              Use <file> as texture for clearcoat.
                                     ch: (optional) texture color channel (r, g, b or a).
                                     fc: (optional) fallback constant in the range [0..1]

-clearcoatRoughness c                Set clearcoat roughness to constant c, in the range [0..1]
-clearcoatRoughness ch <file> fc     Use <file> as texture for clearcoat roughness.
                                     ch: (optional) texture color channel (r, g, b or a).
                                     fc: (optional) fallback constant in the range [0..1]
```

### Reality Converter

Instead of using a command line conversion tool (CLI), you can use a **[Reality Converter](https://developer.apple.com/augmented-reality/tools/)** app (GUI). This app makes it easy to convert, view, and customize `.usdz` models on Mac. Simply drag-and-drop common 3D file formats, such as `.obj`, `.gltf` or `.fbx`, to view the converted `.usdz` result, customize material properties with your own UV-mapped textures, and edit file metadata. You can even preview your `.usdz` object under a variety of lighting and environment conditions with built-in IBL options.

[image]

For `.fbx` conversion you have to download and install [FBX C++ SDK](https://www.autodesk.com/developer-network/platform-technologies/fbx-sdk-2020-2-1).

Needed file is ***FBX SDK 2020.2.1 Clang (Universal Binary)***.

[image]

### `USDZ Export` command in RC and RCP

In ***Reality Composer 1.5*** for ***Xcode 14/13/12*** you can export a `usdz` model right from Reality Composer's UI. For that you just need to activate a USDZ export in RealityComposer – **Preferences** menu.

[image]

In ***Reality Composer Pro 1.0*** for ***Xcode 15*** simply use `File – Export` command.

Also you can use **[AR USD Schemas](https://medium.com/macoclock/augmented-reality-911-usdz-schemas-367ae40c6950)** and, of course, **[Autodesk Maya 2024](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51009105/how-to-create-a-usdz-animation/52347633#52347633)** workflow.

### Create USDZ file from SCN scene

Another way to generate an USDZ file is to convert it from the SceneKit's scene using the [write(to:options:delegate:progressHandler:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnscene/1523577-write) instance method. If you need to generate a SCN scene from DAE file (prior to USDZ convertion), use Xcode's <kbd>Editor</kbd> menu, and `Convert to SCN file format` command.

Here's the code:

```
import SceneKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var sceneView: ARSCNView!
    let scene = SCNScene(named: "art.scnassets/ship.scn")!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        sceneView.scene = scene
        
        let path = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory,
                                             in: .userDomainMask)[0]
                                   .appendingPathComponent("model.usdz")
        
        scene.write(to: path, options: nil, 
              delegate: nil, progressHandler: nil)
        
        print(path)
    }
}
```

[image]

### Create SCN scene from USDZ file

In Xcode 15 you can easily convert USDZ to SCN using UI button.

[image]

### `xcrun usdz_converter` command in Xcode 10

> In ***macOS Mojave 10.14*** and ***Xcode 10*** `USDZ converter` has a slightly different set of arguments and flags. Here's how an old command looks like in **Terminal**:

```
xcrun usdz_converter file.obj file.usdz -color_map color.jpg -ao_map ao.png
```

- *In macOS Mojave the default command shell is* ***BASH***.

Here's a full list of options you can see in Terminal, typing **`xcrun usdz_converter -h`** :

```shell
-g groupName [groupNames ...]        Apply subsequent material properties to the named group(s).
-m materialName [materialNames ...]  Apply subsequent material properties to the named material(s).
-h                                   Display help.
-a                                   Generate a .usda intermediate file.  Default is .usdc.
-l                                   Leave the intermediate .usd file in the source folder.
-v                                   Verbose output.
-f                    filePath       Read commands from a file.
-texCoordSet          set            The name of the texturemap coordinate set to use if multiple exist (no quotes).
-opacity              o              Floating point value 0.0...1.0

-color_default        r g b a        Floating point values 0.0...1.0
-normal_default       r g b a        Floating point values 0.0...1.0
-emissive_default     r g b a        Floating point values 0.0...1.0
-metallic_default     r g b a        Floating point values 0.0...1.0
-roughness_default    r g b a        Floating point values 0.0...1.0
-ao_default           r g b a        Floating point values 0.0...1.0

-color_map            filePath
-normal_map           filePath
-emissive_map         filePath
-metallic_map         filePath
-roughness_map        filePath
-ao_map               filePath
```

Comment: Do you may have any suggestions regarding using just the Python Tool without XCode?

Comment: I am stuck at `Error: failed to import pxr module. Please add path to USD Python bindings to your PYTHONPATH` ... what's the best way to solve this issue?

Comment: Hi @ChrisB! I renamed the library to `usdpython` and placed it inside Mac's `Home` directory. As you can see, the path is the following: `/Users/<UserName>/usdpython/`.

Comment: Thanks @AndyJazz, for the quick answer! I've moved the folder `usdpython` to my `~` folder and adjusted the `.zshrc` paths according to the instructions above to: 

``export PATH="/Users/myuser/usdpython/USD:$PATH"
export PATH="/Users/myuser/usdpython/usdzconvert:$PATH"
export PYTHONPATH="/Users/myuser/usdpython/USD/lib/python:$PYTHONPATH"``

restarted the machine but still get the error. README says it's usdzconvert version 0.64. 

What else can I try?

Comment: I've found the solution: You need to open the terminal in Rosetta mode. Then it works.

Comment: For some reason the Rosetta mode fix does not work anymore and I'm back to the error `Error: failed to import pxr module. Please add path to USD Python bindings to your PYTHONPATH` despite having followed above instructions.

What's the best way to debug this? I installed it on a brand new Mac, using Python from Homebrew.

Comment: I've also been trying the `xcrun` option but get: `xcrun: error: unable to find utility "usdz_converter", not a developer tool or in PATH` ... how can I install it or add it to PATH?

Comment: @ChrisB, what version of Xcode and USDTools are you using (trying to run `xcrun` instead of `usdzconvert`) ??

Comment: USDPython-0.66.pkg will install `usdpython` to `/Applications/usdpython`

Comment: @hstdt, you can change the directory location after installation, and then specify its path in `zsh resource file`.

Answer (score 8):

You have to enable the Xcode 10 command line tools on <kbd>Xcode > Preferences > Locations</kbd>

[image: Example]

Comment: I needed to change from using v. 9 command line tools to using the 10 beta cmd line tools

Answer (score 0):

You have to activate the command line tools in Xcode preferences, in case they're not actived yet (that was my case). See this topic:

[How to create a USDZ file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50686813/how-to-create-a-usdz-file)