# How to generate USDZ file again from ZIP file?

Tags: scenekit, augmented-reality, arkit, usdz, realitykit

Hello everyone I'm trying to unzip a USDZ file, modify a texture, and then zip the USDZ file again, but it breaks.

Is there any special way to zip the file back? Even if I decompress and compress again it stops working and has different file size.

I'm using no compression and no encryption to zip the file. One thing I have noticed is that the attribute "Needed to extract" for the USDZ file is "2.0 or later" while my new zip file value is "1.0 or later". Also the files in the original USDZ zip have some extra fields I cannot read or add to my new file.

What could be happening? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: To pack my modified USDZ file back, I used the tools provided here: https://github.com/PixarAnimationStudios/USD (usdzip) which works in Windows and Linux.

Answer (score 6):

### Unzip `usdz` file

#### To unzip a `usdz` file in macOS use the following steps:

- In Finder change the extension of `.usdz` file to `.zip`.
- Uncompress `.zip` file by double-clicking it.
- Open unzipped directory and change the `.png` textures of your model.
- Open and edit `.aiff`, `.caf` or `mp3` audio files, if any.
- You can import a binary `.usdc` file in Maya 2024 for animation.

---

[image]

#### Create `usdz` file again

Make sure that the latest versions of Xcode and [USDZ Python Tools](https://developer.apple.com/augmented-reality/tools/) are installed.

To convert a content of unzipped folder (binary `usdc` file and its textures) back to `usdz` file format again, use the following command in `Terminal.app`:

```zsh
usdzconvert ~/Desktop/file.usdc -diffuseColor Grammophone_Albedo.png 
                                -metallic Grammophone_Metallic.png
                                -occlusion Grammophone_AO.png
                                -normal Grammophone_Normal.png
                                -roughness Grammophone_Roughness.png
```

And here's an [additional info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50846627/how-to-create-usdz-file-using-xcode-converter/50867018#50867018) about `usdzconvert` command for *Xcode 15/14/13/12/11/10*.

Comment: Thank you, maybe I didn't was specific enough, I need this to modify the textures from a website and then pack it again into a USDZ file.