# RealityKit – Loading USDC model fails with RealityKit.Entity.LoadError error 0

Tags: ios, swift, arkit, realitykit

Loading machine (USDC) ends with **Fatal error: The operation couldn’t be completed. (RealityKit.Entity.LoadError error 0.)**. No more details are provided about the issue.

This is a **nonAR** RealityKit scene. Loading the model while blocking the main thread is intentional here.

Any suggestions what the error may mean? I can't find any explanation.

```swift
func loadMachine() {
    do {
        machine = try Entity.load(named: "Machine")
    } catch let error {
        fatalError(error.localizedDescription) 

        //  Fatal error: The operation couldn’t be completed. 
        //  (RealityKit.Entity.LoadError error 0.)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.usdz` model (also known as binary-encoded zero-compression `zip` file), not `.usdc`. While Apple's Quick Look is capable of showing USDA (ascii) and USDC (binary) models, RealityKit 2.0 and Reality Composer 1.5 read in just USDZ models from the USD family.

The `.usdz` format was specifically created by Pixar in collaboration with Apple for AR.

```
let machine = try! ModelEntity.load(named: "Machine.usdz")
```

To convert USDC to USDZ, use [command line tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50846627/how-to-create-usdz-file-using-xcode-converter/50867018#50867018), or [Autodesk Maya](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51009105/how-to-create-a-usdz-animation/52347633#52347633) 2020+ with USD plug-in.

Comment: USDC is the only one I have.. RealityComposer fails to convert it to USDZ. It doesn't really throw any error, saving this file while converting has no effect..