# ARKit – Save scene as USDZ?

Tags: swift, augmented-reality, scenekit, arkit, realitykit

Right now I can save what I created in ARKit as a scene file, and load it back later.

```
sceneView.scene.write(to: path, options: nil, delegate: nil, progressHandler: nil)
```

But is it possible to save the scene as USDZ file and load it back?

Answer (score 4):

First of all, read the following [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50846627/how-to-create-usdz-file-using-xcode-converter/50867018#50867018) that is very helpful.

#### Creating USDZ from SCN programmatically

In SceneKit, there's the `write(to:options:delegate:progressHandler:)` instance method that does the trick (the only thing you have to do is to assign a file format for URL).

```
let path = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory,
                                     in: .userDomainMask)[0]
                                         .appendingPathComponent("model.usdz")
    
sceneView.scene.write(to: path)
```

#### Converting OBJ to USDZ using SceneKit.ModelIO

However, if you need to convert `OBJ` model into `USDZ`, you have to import `SceneKit.ModelIO` module at first. Then use the following code:

```
let objAsset = MDLAsset(url: objFileUrl)
let destinationFileUrl = URL(fileURLWithPath: "path/Scene.usdz")
objAsset.exportToUSDZ(destinationFileUrl: destinationFileUrl)
```

#### Terminal approach

**In Xcode 15/14/13/12/11**, you can convert several popular input formats into **USDZ** via command line: `obj`, `gltf`, `fbx`, `abc`, `usd(x)`.

```bash
usdzconvert file.gltf
```

**In Xcode 10**, only **`OBJ-to-USDZ`**, single-frame **`ABC-to-USDZ`**  and **`USD(x)-to-USDZ`** conversion is available via command line:

```bash
xcrun usdz_converter file.obj file.usdz
```

#### Preparing files for RealityKit

In Xcode 15+ you can use a ***Reality Composer Pro*** software for converting any RCP scene into `usdz` file format (right from UI). Also, there's a ***Reality Converter*** standalone app.

And, of course, you can use Autodesk Maya 2024 with [Maya USD plugin](https://github.com/Autodesk/maya-usd/releases).