# usdz_converter[3551:150562] Could not open OBJ file asset_validation: error: No data found in file

Tags: ios, xcode10, ios12, usdz

I am getting **usdz_converter[3551:150562] Could not open OBJ file
asset_validation: error: No data found in file** when i try to convert .obj file to usdz file using Xcode 10 Beta.

I followed this thread [How to create USDZ file using Xcode 10 converter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50846627/how-to-create-usdz-file-using-xcode-10-converter/50867018#50867018) to do the conversion.

I have correctly set my Xcode 10 Beta as default xcode application in terminal and mapped command line tools to Xcode 10 Beta. Can anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

For reference, here's how I've converted an .obj file to .usdz. Currently running Xcode 10.1

```
xcrun usdz_converter <infile>.obj <outfile>.usdz -color_map <texture>.jpg
```