# How to convert .obj and .htl into USDZ?

Tags: swift, xcode, augmented-reality

I need a USDZ file for a simple AR app.

Question is, I’m getting a .obj + .htl file from my 3d Designer.

How do add this to my Reality Composer/Xcode project?

I’m able to convert the .obj to USDZ. But this gives me just a plain, white object. I understand the .htl is just an instruction file? So am I missing a .png file from my designer? Or can we essentially get some sort of color/texture information out of this file?

Comment: ask your designer to send the FBX file (there's no excuse for 3d designers to not be able to export it), and then follow instructions in the top answer of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56493972/is-there-any-way-to-load-fbx-file-using-arkit)

Answer (score 0):

Apple has a [USDZ converter](https://developer.apple.com/download/more/?=USDPython). It should work with obj files as well.