# In SceneKit, if you do use a usdz file for a model/animation, how the heck to you play the MDLPackedJointAnimation?

Tags: swift, animation, scenekit

Have a usdz file with the typical one character and one animation.

```
    let p = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Sitting Laughing", withExtension: "usdz")!
    let amyAsset = MDLAsset(url: p)
    amyAsset.loadTextures()
    let amy = SCNNode(mdlObject: amyAsset.object(at: 0))
    .. your node .. .addChildNode(amy)
```

You can now see "amy" perfectly in your scene.

If you try this, notice there are NO keys:

```
    for k in amy.animationKeys { print("keys? \(k)") }
```

however try this with the asset,

```
    for ob in amyAsset.animations.objects { print("ob \(ob)") }
```

And you'll see the `MDLPackedJointAnimation` for example

> <<MDLPackedJointAnimation: 0x7ff7b0e18830>, Name:
> /High_Jump/mixamorig_Hips/Skeleton/Animation, Children: 0>

Alternately, say,

```
    let pjs = amyAsset.animations.objects.compactMap { $0 as? MDLPackedJointAnimation }
    for pj in pjs {
        print("... \(pj.name)")
    }
```

for the same info.

The "name" will look like `/High_Jump/mixamorig_Hips/Skeleton/Animation`

From there how the heck do you **play** that `MDLPackedJointAnimation` ???

I've tried everything and cannot :/

Comment: do you involve any DAE files in your animation?

Comment: is your goal to animate a Mixamo character?

Comment: @ZAY exactly correct, mixamo.  I am happy to use a dae file instead (and I'm, trying that as well, but it's definitley a bit weird).  Using usdz (as above) you can indeed get the animation (well, the `MDLPackedJointAnimation`) I just can't figure out how the hell to (I assume) mak ethat a CAAnimation and then play it on the node ...  :/

Comment: I made a question!  @ZAY  It seems totally impossible to simply get a Mixamo dae file to animate, in, a SceneKit scene :/  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75090481

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be the case that the `MDLPackedJointAnimation` is a low-level representation of the animation(s) of the joints.

It's only possible to "play" a packed joint animation in the sense of completely manually animating it yourself using a display link and so on.

Article which touches on that:

https://medium.com/@warrenm/thirty-days-of-metal-day-28-skinning-690fe46785c9

It seems that `MDLPackedJointAnimation` is completely unrelated to the `CAAnimation` concepts in iOS, that is to say, there is no "command" or way whatsoever to "just play" a `MDLPackedJointAnimation` set of information.