# When I try to run "xcrun usdz_convert" I get an error

Tags: terminal, augmented-reality, arkit, xcrun, usdz

I updated to macOS Catalina 10.15 and Xcode 11.0. Now this command is not running now:

```
xcrun usdz_convert
```

I get this error even though I've updated both `$PATH` and `$PYHONPATH` variables:

```
xcrun: error: unable to find utility "usdz_convert", not a developer tool or in PATH
```

Is there any fix for this yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In macOS Catalina 10.15.5 with `Xcode 11` installed, or higher macOS with `Xcode 12` or `Xcode 13` installed, you need to use a new `USDZ` converter command in command line interface:

```
usdzconvert file.fbx
```

But before using this command check if `USDPython Tools` is installed.

For more info, please read **[this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50846627/how-to-create-usdz-file-using-xcode-converter/50867018#50867018)**.