# How can I solve USDZConvert Pxr Import Error?

Tags: bash, augmented-reality, arkit, realitykit, reality-converter

I'm running into this issue after installing USDZ tools from Apple's website. I'm a bit rusty at Python and tried installing all the underlying packages.

I set my `PYTHONPATH` already using `export PYTHONPATH="/Users/gt/usdpython/USD/lib/python:$PYTHONPATH"`

```
USD git:(master) ✗ usdzconvert
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/gt/usdpython/usdzconvert/usdzconvert", line 17, in <module>
    usdUtils.printError("failed to import pxr module. Please add path to USD Python bindings to your PYTHONPATH.")
NameError: name 'usdUtils' is not defined
```

Answer (score 7):

> Download the latest version – **`usdpython 0.66`** from `https://developer.apple.com`.
>
> You need to paste these 3 lines inside `.zshrc` file – you can see how to create it [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50846627/how-to-create-usdz-file-using-xcode-converter/50867018#50867018).

```
export PYTHONPATH="/Users/gt/usdpython/USD/lib/python:$PYTHONPATH"
export PATH="/Users/gt/usdpython/USD:$PATH"
export PATH="/Users/gt/usdpython/usdzconvert:$PATH"
```

**P.S.**

Do not use the version of **`usdpython_0.63`** (Feb 5, 2020) because it unfortunately causes errors.

Comment: Thanks. I have that in my `.zshrc`, but it's still throwing the same error.

My PYTONPATH:
`echo $PYTHONPATH
/Users/gt/usdpython/USD/lib/python:`

The `PATH` includes those two strings

Comment: @aspdev91, please, let me know whether it works or not.

Comment: This solved the problem for me. Also you don't have to set the path in .zshrc file. Clicking on the USD.command file exports all the required paths for that shell instance

Comment: I ended up just using the Reality Converter GUI tool provided by Apple here 

https://developer.apple.com/services-account/download?path=/Applications/Reality_Converter/Reality_Converter_Beta.dmg

Thanks everyone!

Comment: Was having a lot of issues with this too. Downloading the 0.62 version worked for me, now I can open USD.command everything is working. Thanks!

Comment: What kind of insider information is this "0.63 is broken" ??? Andy you're a torch bearer...

Comment: Hi @PavelZdenek, I haven't found any insiders' info on `usdpython_0.63`, can't tell you why it's broken((

Comment: I can't seem to get this to work. Getting the error `Error: failed to import pxr module. Please add path to USD Python bindings to your PYTHONPATH`

https://imgur.com/a/uBDatMS

Comment: @ChrisB, try running another library (not usdpython) - and see if it works. If another library also gives any errors, then you have a problem with your command line.

Comment: @AndyJazz thanks for your suggestion. Apologies, not sure what you mean. How can I run another library? Other python scripts seem fine. I've also tried another machine, (Mac Mini), installed USD Tools from the Apple website from scratch, followed instructions and run into the exact same error as on my macbook. Also, I can `import pxr` without error if I use the python interactive shell.

Comment: What are your macOS and Xcode versions?

Comment: macOS is Monterey with the latest Xcode, but I've found the solution: *You need to open the terminal in Rosetta mode. Then it works.* Thanks for your offer to help!

Comment: For anyone looking for the different versions, you can find them here: https://developer.apple.com/download/all/?q=USD

Answer (score 1):

Run Rosetta Terminal fixes it.
https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/671459