# Load DAE file in a SwiftUI RealityKit app

Tags: swift, swiftui, augmented-reality, arkit, realitykit

I have a SwiftUI app in which I am trying to display a `.dae` file with RealityKit framework.

Is that even possible? Or can it only load `.reality` and `.usdz` files?
I got it working with a simple box created in code, but rendering a model seems to be problematic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> In RealityKit you can use three file formats specifically made for it: `.usdz`, `.rcproject` and `.reality`. Mentioned file formats have hierarchical structure that correlates with RealityKit's guts.

If you prepared your model in other file format (`.obj`, `.gltf`, `.fbx`, `.abc`, `.usda`, `.usdc`, `.usd`) use [usdzconvert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50846627/how-to-create-usdz-file-using-xcode-converter/50867018#50867018) command for converting it in `.usdz`.

**P.S.**

Both `.dae` and `.scn` file formats were implemented to use them inside SceneKit's SCNView and ARKit's ARSCNView. So, you can't load a `.dae` model into RealityKit view.

Comment: Thx for the clarification andy!