# How to export in USDZ format in Reality Composer?

Tags: augmented-reality, arkit, realitykit, reality-composer

I want to export model in usdz format from reality composer but I am not getting the option.

As per [apple](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/realitykit/creating_3d_content_with_reality_composer/exporting_a_reality_composer_scene_to_usdz) user would get option to enable USDZ export in preference of reality composer but I am not getting that option.

[image: Actual Image]

Image From apple website

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In **Reality Composer 1.5** (which is a part of Xcode 12) go to `Preferences` menu and enable `USDZ Export`. For more detailed info read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50846627/how-to-create-usdz-file-using-xcode-converter/50867018#50867018).