# Improve load time of large `.reality` files

Tags: augmented-reality, arkit, realitykit, arquicklook, web-ar

So I have a large (138mb) reality file that I want to user to be able to interact with via Safari quick view.

So I have done the following:

```
<a
  href="...link to .reality file"
  rel="ar"
>
  <img />
</a>
```

now obviously since its such a large file it takes a few minutes to download, now the apple docs are not great when it comes to the web side of reality kit so I'm wondering if there is anything I can do to improve the experience for the user?

Answer (score 0):

3D models for AR and VR apps are determined by polygon count and texture size, not MB (the size in MB is important when uploading/downloading a file over the internet). Apple documentation clearly says about [assets for RealityKit](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/adding_visual_effects_in_ar_quick_look_and_realitykit):

> ...Keep the polygon count of your 3D asset's geometry below 100,000 polygons.

So, your asset contains significantly more polygons than needed. However, [models with 25K polys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65637882/arkit-getting-unexpectedly-found-nil-when-using-scn-file-300-mb/65642069#65642069) (or lower) will load much faster. Another important aspect is textures. Apple says about that:

> ...For textures, don't surpass a size of 2048 x 2048 pixels (1024 x 1024 is preferable).

You can check a polygons count for `.usdz` files in Attributes Inspector in Xcode.

[image]

The size of the file `House.usdz` is 8.4 MB.