# Executing usdzconvert -h and getting env: python 3.7 no such file or directory found

Tags: swift, arkit

1. USDZ tool downloaded from https://developer.apple.com/augmented-reality/tools/
2. MAC -> MacOS BigSur
3. Python -> 2.7 and 3.10
4. When trying to execute USD.command getting error as "env: python 3.7 no such file or directory found"
5. Installed python3.7 and tried but got another error that the version was not compatible with the mac config.

Please let me know if anyone has faced this kind of issue and have a working solution for this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hope this helps - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50846627/how-to-create-usdz-file-using-xcode-converter/50867018#50867018

Comment: @AndyJazz It has nothing to do about the error, still getting it.

Comment: Hi @EdwardMordrake, It's hard to say what exactly the problem is. There are many possible causes for the errors.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue and fixed it by installing Python 3.7 from Python's website.

You can download and install Python 3.7.9 (recommended by Apple) from https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-379/.

Note: After installing Python 3.7 be sure to execute "Install Certificates.command” as mentioned in the installer's instructions.