# 3D artwork that is exported as USDZ has different colors

Tags: swift, swiftui, scenekit, maya, realitykit

I want to start by saying that I am new to SceneKit and playing with AR environments on iOS.

I have a 3D model object, a van, as part of a Blender file(.blend) --> it can be found [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1v7TsZjblRVWSK2r8v2AC1dVokJWfaqku/view?usp=sharing).

I am exporting it as a .glb file from Blender --> it can be found [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1EkQKIl_dOAsJ7SwDRHQjGE3jEVAw62KS/view?usp=sharing).

Then I open the .glb file in Reality Converter app, and export it as a .usdz file --> it can be found [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zi3mNZRhU-uyfI2y24kW99AO5KWuvLeu/view?usp=sharing).

**The issue is when I preview the object in XCode and also when I place it in AR, the object colours are wrong.**

Is there a problem with the Blender object? If so, what should I change to it so that the colours are exported correctly?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### About Blender, Maya and Xcode

Unfortunately, the issue you mentioned here is a great [old issue in Blender](https://devtalk.blender.org/t/big-color-problem-color-is-never-reliable-is-there-a-possible-solution/13804). Indeed, Blender outputs wrong (a.k.a. inconsistent) shaders' colors, due to the fact that Blender operates in linear color space (not sRGB) of shader colors. There are 2 possible solutions in this case. The first one is quite radical - to use a real PRO software, like Autodesk Maya 2023 with [USD plugin](https://github.com/Autodesk/maya-usd/releases) (because it takes a decent amount of time to learn Maya), in which exported shaders' colors are reproduced very accurately in correct color space – you must reassign all the materials from scratch. The second one – fix colors in Xcode's inspector manually, or programmatically.

From Maya you can export your model as **binary** or **ASCII** `.usd` file format (make sure that MayaUSD plugin is loaded). Then use Reality Converter, to convert the resulting model in `.usdz` archive.

### Xcode solution

Load your `van.usdz` model into Xcode. Rename model's nodes in hierarchy for convenience.

[image]

***Very important!***

Select `Body_Orange` node and go to `Attributes Inspector` tab. Delete `Colors` attribute.

`Colors` attribute keeps `.usdz` colour schema.

[image]

Then in `Material Inspector` assign a needed `Diffuse` color of `physicallyBased` shader.

[image]

Also, you can do it programmatically. Here's a SwiftUI sample code for SceneKit:

```
import SwiftUI
import SceneKit
...

func makeUIView(context: Context) -> SCNView {

    let sceneView = SCNView(frame: .zero)
    sceneView.scene = SCNScene(named: "van.usdz")
    
    let orangeBody = sceneView.scene?.rootNode.childNodes[0].childNodes[0]
        .childNodes[0].childNode(withName: "Body_Orange", recursively: true)

    orangeBody?.geometry?.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = 
          UIColor(red: 218/255, green: 154/255, blue: 93/255, alpha: 255/255)

    let blueBody = sceneView.scene?.rootNode.childNodes[0].childNodes[0]
        .childNodes[0].childNode(withName: "Body_Blue", recursively: true)

    blueBody?.geometry?.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = 
          UIColor(red: 58/255, green: 150/255, blue: 207/255, alpha: 255/255)

    sceneView.backgroundColor = .black
    sceneView.autoenablesDefaultLighting = true
    sceneView.allowsCameraControl = true
    sceneView.showsStatistics = true

    return sceneView
}
```

And here's a SwiftUI sample code for RealityKit version:

```
import SwiftUI
import RealityKit
...

func makeUIView(context: Context) -> ARView {
    
    let arView = ARView(frame: .zero)
    arView.backgroundColor = .black
    
    let vanModel = try! ModelEntity.load(named: "van.usdz")
     
    let orangeBodyPart = vanModel.children[0].children[0].children[0]
                                 .children[0].children[0] as! ModelEntity
    let colorOrange = UIColor(red: 218/255, green: 154/255, 
                             blue: 93/255, alpha: 255/255)
    orangeBodyPart.model?.materials = [SimpleMaterial(color: colorOrange, 
                                                 isMetallic: false)]
    
    let blueBodyPart = vanModel.children[0].children[0].children[0]
                               .children[0].children[1] as! ModelEntity
    let colorBlue = UIColor(red: 58/255, green: 150/255, 
                           blue: 207/255, alpha: 255/255)
    blueBodyPart.model?.materials = [SimpleMaterial(color: colorBlue, 
                                               isMetallic: false)]

    let anchor = AnchorEntity(world: [0, 0,-5])
    vanModel.setParent(anchor)
    arView.scene.anchors.append(anchor)        
    return arView
}
```

[image]

### A few words on poly count and retopology in Maya

I would like to make one remark about the polygons' count in your model. Such a simple model can be made having 2K to 5K polygons. But your model has over 50,000 polygons, which is a tremendous number. Your hi-poly model will consume a lot of resources (CPU, GPU, memory), thus, drop frame is possible (58 fps, as you can see in the picture).

So, what can you do about it? Ideally, it's a 3D modeler's job to conceive and create low-poly models for games and mobile platforms – it's really a precious skill. Modifying an already finished mesh (saved to distribution formats like **.fbx** or **.usdz**) is often a bad idea. However, Autodesk Maya for example, has a retopology tool (`Mesh –> Retopologize`) that helps you significantly reduce the number of polygons using advanced algorithm. Watch the [official video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0LKrSvMatpA) (Time - 00:50).

[image]

Comment: So, what would be the steps? Save the model in what format so that it can be open in Maya and further export it as usdz?

Comment: Import your car model as `.usd` or `.dae` or `.fbx` or `.obj` into Maya, then assign new Maya shaders with correct colors (create a new UV map if needed), and then export a model as `.usd` or `.fbx`.

Comment: Then use USDZ conversion tools – https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50846627/how-to-create-usdz-file-using-xcode-converter/50867018#50867018

Comment: @ andy-jazz, thank you , I will test it now. Also, sorry to bother you, how can one reduce the polygon count? Would it still look the same? I am asking because the model is not done by me.

Comment: Ideally, it's a 3D modeler's job to conceive and create a low-poly models (it's a cool skill). Modifying an already finished mesh is always bad. But, Maya for example, has a retopology tool (Mesh –> Retopologize.). https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0LKrSvMatpA (Time - 00:55).

Comment: Take into consideration, AR and VR scenes on iOS must have not greater than 100K polygons. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/adding_visual_effects_in_ar_quick_look_and_realitykit