# How can i import a model with animations from Blender into RealityKit?

Tags: swift, swiftui, blender, realitykit

I made a simple `cube model` with animation in Blender.
Exported it as a `.fbx` file with the option `bake animation` turned on.

With `Reality Converter` I converted the `.fbx` file to `.usdz` which I imported into my Xcode project. But I am not getting the animation back in my project (see below for the code).

```
import SwiftUI
import RealityKit

struct ContentView : View {
    var body: some View {
        ARViewContainer().edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
    }
}

struct ARViewContainer: UIViewRepresentable {
    
    let arView = ARView(frame: .zero)
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> ARView {
        
        let anchorEntity = AnchorEntity()
        
        //get local usdz file which is in xcode project
        do {               
            let cubeModel = try ModelEntity.load(named: "cube")
            print(cubeModel)                
            print(cubeModel.availableAnimations) // here i get an empty array

            anchorEntity.addChild(cubeModel)               
            arView.scene.addAnchor(anchorEntity)
          }
          catch {
             print(error)
          }
        return arView   // the cube is visible on my ipad  
    }        
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: ARView, context: Context) { }
}
```

For what i understand is has to be possible to import with animations. Am i missing something ?

Answer (score 4):

### FBX model with character animation

Make sure you exported a model from Blender with enabled animation. To play animation in RealityKit use AnimationPlaybackController object. To test a character animation in RealityKit use [this fbx model](https://free3d.com/3d-model/nathan-animated-003-walking-644277.html?__cf_chl_tk=FQNbiFEjsjCXSMUSpP4FRv98KblkgFEryp3SFj14Qv4-1674030781-0-gaNycGzNCJE).

To convert `.fbx` model to `.usdz` use [Reality Converter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50846627/how-to-create-usdz-file-using-xcode-converter/50867018#50867018).

[image]

```
import SwiftUI
import RealityKit

struct ContentView : View {
    var body: some View {
        ARViewContainer()
            .ignoresSafeArea()
    }
}

struct ARViewContainer: UIViewRepresentable {
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> ARView {

        let arView = ARView(frame: .zero)
        let model = try! Entity.loadModel(named: "walking.usdz")
        let anchor = AnchorEntity(world: [0,-1,-2])
        model.setParent(anchor)
        arView.scene.anchors.append(anchor)

        let animation: AnimationResource = model.availableAnimations[0]
        let controller = model.playAnimation(animation.repeat())
        controller.blendFactor = 0.5
        controller.speed = 1.7

        return arView
    }
    func updateUIView(_ view: ARView, context: Context) { }
}
```

Comment: this is not working, no animations in the animationslist of the object with fbx format

Comment: Yep, this model is working with my code, so with ModelEntity.load. Conclusion is that my own model from Blender is not right. So i have a cube and a plane under it, the cube is falling on the plane. Thats all, i select fbx and baked animation.  I dont do anything with keyframes in blender, probably i have to dig in blender.

Comment: If so, it seems it's really Blender's issue.

Comment: Yes, but the usd format in blender works also after converting it with realityconverter.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer in blender, i did the export in USD format with animations on.
Then convert the file in realityconverter to usdz format, now the model and the animations are in my xcode project.